# How can I ensure that I receive a transferred domain name after sending the money to pay for it?

Tags: domains, payments, domain-transfer

I am about to purchase a domain name for a bit of money. I do not personally know the person who I am purchasing the domain name from, we have only chatted via email.

The proposed process for the transfer is:

1. The owner of the domain lowers the
   domain name security and emails me
   the domain password, I request the
   transfer
2. After the request, I transfer the money via PayPal
3. When the money has been cleared the current domain name owner confirms the transfer via the link that he receives in that email
4. I wait for it to be transferred.

The domain is currently registered with DirectNIC - http://www.directnic.com/

Is this the best practice? Seeing I am paying a bit of money for this domain name, I am worried that after the money has been cleared that I won't see the domain name or hear from the current domain name owner again.

Is there a 'domain governing body' which I can report to if this is the case?
Is the proposed transfer process the best solution?

Comment: Have you confirmed that they legitimately own the domain and if the purchase went ahead you would be the legitimate owner? If so then I would check with the domain registrar what they could do for you.

Comment: The domain is currently with DirectNIC. I have emailed them (and am waiting to hear back from them). 

When I first contacted them about the domain name owner, they were the ones who gave me the contact details for the owner.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an escrow service. With an escrow service, it would hold your payment until the transaction is complete, and will return it if it turns out that the transfer is not allowed. Using a service like this would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive there is no such thing as domain password. Also I don't understand what the domain owners says by "lower the domain name security". The only password I know is in this case the user account at DirectNIC which I doubt it will share. I would proceed with great caution and use an escrow services as suggested by Ofir.